# How do I delete all my Ubuntu One contacts?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, contacts

I want to sync my new cell phone contacts but I want to erase all the contacts that I have in my Ubuntu One account first. I use android 2.2 on my phone, on the application I select just to upload contacts but its not doing that, it is replacing the one I have on my cell.

Answer (score 1):

> Delete a contact
>
> - Click on the letter of the contact's last name that you want to edit and
>     then click on the contact's link .
> - Click on the trash icon .
>
> [image]
>
> - Click on the Delete button when asked to confirm the deletion of the
>     contact
>
> [image]
>
> - Screen refreshes and the deleted contact is no longer there .

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Contacts#Delete%20a%20contact)